# Name for this kind of drawing with extremely small heads, no hands, no attempt to respect any scale, flat surfaces

Tags: style-identification, character-design

[image]

I guess it's a sub genre of flat design, but is there something more to it ? Are they trolling us by making the head smaller and smaller ?

Comment: Not everything has a name. I doubt you will find something more precise than "flat design with small heads", but who knows? There are so many ways to draw and so many trends interweaving. They normally don't get a name before they are gone again and we can see their attributes and effect in retrospect.

Comment: See also [Corporate Memphis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_Memphis)

Comment: I will also say that I think the origins of this kind of illustration style go back further than the date implied in the wikipedia article I linked to. There are elements of this style which are visible in work from the 1960's - [for example](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b8/78/44/b878446edda6a28220a05482c44aadfc.jpg), possibly even earlier to modern styles of art in the early 20th century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it was inspired by ‘Corporate Memphis’

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_Memphis

Initially launched by Facebook as ‘Alegria’ this style quickly became popular among tech companies.

Quoting Wikipedia:

Common motifs are flat human characters in action, with disproportionate features such as long and bendy limbs, small torsos, minimal or no facial features, and bright colors without any blending.

See also this excellent video on the history of clip art by Linus Boman:

https://youtu.be/XfLlpxE6AYM

Answer (score -1):

Call them The Blutons or say "they are drawn in the Blutonian style". Check this for the deeper meaning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluto.

Nothing prevents you using your own style name, but it's always better to use the established already well known name.